# Changing color of overlapping plots

Tags: plotting, filling

If I have two plots with two different colors,

```
Plot[{Sin[x]^2, Sin[10 x]^2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

is there a way to change the color of the overlapping line? I don't want to fill rather change the overlapping part only. I wanted to do this for `ListLinePlot` if possible!

In the following plot blue curve is on top of the red one. What I want is every time the blue and red overlap change the color of the overlapping line.

```
Plot[{Sin[x]^2, Sin[5 x]^2}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[.02]], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.02]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thank you!

Comment: Adding `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}` yields [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx37E.png). Is that along the lines of what you want? Perhaps you could define what you mean by "overlapping region" in your case.

Comment: I meant overlapping line.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that I don't understand what/where the overlapping line is. Could you clarify further?

Comment: In the following plot http://s32.postimg.org/541nyxc3p/test.png blue curve is on top of the red one, what I want is every time the blue and red overlap change the color of the overlapping line. Thank you!

Comment: @crossingsymmetry, I added your last comment and a variant of the linked  picture  to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) are useful here.

```
Plot[{Sin[x]^2, Sin[10 x]^2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#]^2 - Sin[10 #]^2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Green]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is what I wanted, is there a way to do this with ListLinePlot?

Comment: you would need to use `Interpolation`, at which point you could ultimately go back to using `Plot`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)
```

Unfortunately, `MeshFunctions` does not work fully for all cases. For your second example,

```
Plot[{Sin[x]^2, Sin[5 x]^2}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#]^2 - Sin[5 #]^2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[5]}]
```

[image]

Note that overlaps at the extrema are not shown. A more reliable method is to `Solve` for the intersections and use `Epilog`.

```
xVal = Solve[{Sin[x]^2 == Sin[5 x]^2, 0 <= x <= 5}, x, Reals] // FullSimplify // Union
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[x]^2, Sin[5 x]^2}, {x, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}},
 Epilog -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{x, Sin[x]^2} /. xVal]}]
```

[image]

The overlap at the extrema is now shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can always find the intersection separately and then do what you want. For example,

```
f1[x_] = Sin[x]^2;
f2[x_] = Sin[10 x]^2;
pts = x /. NSolve[{f1[x] == f2[x], 0 < x < 5}, x];
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
Prolog -> {Green,Evaluate[{Opacity[0.5], Disk[{#, f1[#]}, {5, 1} 0.02] & /@ pts}]}]
```

[image]